# Modify Group By to achieve correct results

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate

I have large data set with historical data of the INACTIVE Clients and their billing (services) information. I need to group data by ClientId, Service and Year AND produce aggregated fields, such as TotalCharges, TotalProvidedServices and DaysStayedWithUs (Issue with this column).

I was able successfully Group data by ClientId and Service, however grouping by Year producing the wrong result and I know why.

The reason is because Year column produced from ServiceDate column, that originally was used for creating FirstServiceDate and LastServiceDate => to be able produce DaysStayedWithUs (LastServiceDate - FirstServiceDate will give us Amount of Days the Client was with Us (DaysStayedWithUs)). And when I Group by Year, query finds FirstServiceDate, LastServiceDate and calculates DaysStayedWithUs based on it....therefore I have to find another way to achieve result I need (showed below).

Client Table:

```
 ClientId

1234567890
```

Billing Table:

```
ClientId       Service      ServiceDate   ChargesTotal

1234567890     Cleaning       12/4/2018       190.17
1234567890     Cleaning       1/22/2019        97.8
1234567890     Cleaning       1/29/2019        97.8
1234567890     Cleaning       2/5/2019         97.8
1234567890     Cleaning       2/12/2019        97.8
1234567890     Cleaning       3/5/2019         97.8
1234567890     Cleaning       2/19/2019        97.8
1234567890     Cleaning       3/12/2019        97.8
1234567890     Cleaning       3/19/2019        97.8
1234567890     Cleaning       3/26/2019        97.8
```

My code:

```
SELECT GroupedTable.ClientId, 
        GroupedTable.Service, 
        ---GroupedTable.Year,
        GroupedTable.FirstServiceDate, 
        GroupedTable.LastServiceDate, 
        GroupedTable.TotalCharges, 
        GroupedTable.TotalProvidedServices, 
        GroupedTable.DaysStayedWithUs

FROM (SELECT MainTable.ClientId, 
        MainTable.Service,
        SUM(MainTable.Charges) AS TotalCharges,      
        COUNT(*) AS TotalProvidedServices, 
        DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(MainTable.ServiceDate), MAX(MainTable.ServiceDate)) as DaysStayedWithUs,
        ---MainTable.Year,
        MIN(MainTable.ServiceDate) AS FirstServiceDate,
        MAX(MainTable.ServiceDate) AS LastServiceDate

        FROM (SELECT c.ClientId, 
                b.Service,
                b.ServiceDate,
                ---YEAR(b.ServiceDate) AS Year, 
                b.Charges

            FROM Client as c

            LEFT JOIN Billing as b
                ON (c.ClientId = b.ClientId)

            WHERE b.ClientId = 1234567890

            ) as MainTable

---GROUP BY MainTable.ClientId, MainTable.ServiceIdentifier, MainTable.Year) AS GroupedTable
GROUP BY MainTable.ClientId, MainTable.Service) AS GroupedTable
```

Code above produces correct results: (Year deselected)

[image]

If I include Year in the Group By, output is:

[image]

**P.S. I marked cells in Yellow that have issues (technically FirstServiceDate and LastServiceDate are need to be corrected and then DaysStayedWithUs will be adjusted by itself)**

Result I need to accomplish:

[image]

Hope it is possible to achieve.
Thank You.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: And you need to provide sample data that would produce those desired results.

Comment: There's no point in doing an outer join then filtering on the inner table.

Comment: `case when year(min(ServiceDate)) = min(ServiceDate) over () then min(ServiceDate) else datefromparts(year(min(ServiceDate)), 1, 1) end as FirstServiecDate` Last date is similar.

Comment: Added data in the original post. Thank You.

Comment: @shawnt00, I'm having problems implementing your code. The error is:
Column 'MainTable.ServiceDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
I'm new in SQL and can make simple mistakes. Could you please point me in the right direction?
I inserted it in the 2nd Select (instead of MIN(MainTable.ServiceDate) AS FirstServiceDate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the window functions `MIN OVER` and `MAX OVER` in order to see whether a year is the first/last year for a client and service.

```
SELECT 
  c.clientid, 
  b.service,
  YEAR(b.servicedate) as year, 
  SUM(b.charges) AS total_charges,
  COUNT(*) AS total_provided_services
  CASE WHEN YEAR(b.servicedate) = MIN(YEAR(b.servicedate)) OVER (PARTITION BY c.clientid, b.service)
    THEN MIN(b.servicedate) ELSE DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(b.servicedate), 1, 1)
  END AS first_service_date, 
  CASE WHEN YEAR(b.servicedate) = MAX(YEAR(b.servicedate)) OVER (PARTITION BY c.clientid, b.service)
    THEN MAX(b.servicedate) ELSE DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(b.servicedate), 12, 31)
  END AS last_service_date,
  DATEDIFF(DAY, 
    CASE WHEN YEAR(b.servicedate) = MIN(YEAR(b.servicedate)) OVER (PARTITION BY c.clientid, b.service)
      THEN MIN(b.servicedate) ELSE DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(b.servicedate), 1, 1) END, 
    CASE WHEN YEAR(b.servicedate) = MAX(YEAR(b.servicedate)) OVER (PARTITION BY c.clientid, b.service)
      THEN MAX(b.servicedate) ELSE DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(b.servicedate), 12, 31) END 
  ) AS days_stayed_with_us
FROM client AS c
LEFT JOIN billing AS b ON b.clientid = c.clientid
WHERE c.clientid = 1234567890
GROUP BY c.clientid, b.service, YEAR(b.timebillingservicedate)
ORDER BY c.clientid, b.service, YEAR(b.timebillingservicedate);
```

Comment: There are 4 ' ) ' in DATEFROMPARTS Function, that need to be removed. But the output is actually what I was looking for. Million Thank You :)